# PHP output styling

Tags: php, styling

I have this php output

```
<?=($event ['Field'])?>: 

<?=($event['Value'])?>
```

If i surround it with a div the line seams to break making these two outputs apear on separate lines on the doc.

How would I make the field bold without effecting the positioning of the value?

Comment: Note the parentheses are meaningless here: `<?= $event['Value'] ?>` works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a span (along with the relevant CSS):

```
<span class="field-name"><?= $event['Field'] ?></span>:
<?= $event['Value'] ?>
```

`div`s have an implicit `display: block`, which prevents them flowing with text.

Answer (score 0):

Or either define classes for these divs, so make them in CSS To float on the same row